# Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1c9d41e0

Tags: java, android

This is the other problem:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file /Users/bungaallysah/AndroidStudioProjects/splashscreen/app/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1c9d41e0.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@23f7a22d.). Check logs for more details.
```

I've tried to setup the gradle, but there's no problem with that.

Comment: Have you tried invalidating and restarting?

Comment: yes i had tried it

Comment: Can you post your `values.xml`?